# Reload Page without Menu reload in Angular 10

Tags: menu, reload, pageload, angular10

**We are using SSR (server-side rendering) in Angular 10**

**We need to reload the pages without loading the menu every time when the menu clicked**

Is this possible to achieve it in angular 10, if yes,  let me know how this can be handled? which document we should refer to achieve it?